# iOS External accessories framework to connect iPod using bluetooth

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, external-accessory

I am using EADemo from apple

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/EADemo/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010079-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2

This is basically External Accessories framework demo code

My info.plist have

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>audio</string>
        <string>bluetooth-central</string>
        <string>bluetooth-peripheral</string>
        <string>external-accessory</string>
        <string>fetch</string>
        <string>location</string>
        <string>newsstand-content</string>
        <string>remote-notification</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedExternalAccessoryProtocols</key>
    <array>
        <string>com.apple.p1</string>
        <string>com.apple.p2</string>
    </array>
```

[image]
When I run this code

```
_eaSessionController = [EADSessionController sharedController];
_accessoryList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager] connectedAccessories]];

    if ([_accessoryList count] == 0) {
        [_noExternalAccessoriesPosterView setHidden:NO];
    } else {
        [_noExternalAccessoriesPosterView setHidden:YES];
    }
```

The count is always 0. I have paired a Mac Mini and an iPod with the device I am using and I believe these two are MFi complaint obviously.

What am I missing ? can anybody help please ?

Comment: It would probably help if you provided details of the device. Also, is it indeed a Classic Bluetooth device, rather than a BLE device?

Comment: It is not a BLE device. It is iPod. Though I can configure it as BLE peripheral but my aim to connect MFi classical bluetooth accessories such as speakers or headset etc. So I want to explore the classical bluetooth operations.

Answer (score 0):

Okay After a huge research I found this. First of all apple does not take an iPod connected through cable or Bluetooth as an accessory.

Next if any accessories connected through, it will show but you cant communicate with it if it is not under apple's MFi (Made for iOS) licence program and it is induced from iOS 10. Now how do you know the protocol string if the device is under MFi already. Here you need to contact the vendor or manufacturer to get the protocol string as it is sensitive data.